# draw only straight line not smooth

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, draw

```
 -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
mouseSwiped = YES;

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:scrollView];

//[self drawLine:lastPoint.x :lastPoint.y :currentPoint.x :currentPoint.y]; 
tempShapeLayer = nil;
CGMutablePathRef linePath = nil;
linePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
tempShapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

tempShapeLayer.lineWidth = 4.0f;
tempShapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineJoinMiter;
tempShapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];


CGPathMoveToPoint(linePath, NULL, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(linePath, NULL, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);


tempShapeLayer.path = linePath;
CGPathRelease(linePath);

[scrollView.layer addSublayer:tempShapeLayer];

lastPoint = currentPoint;
```

}

i am drawing line by this code . but i want this line remain straight. means when i move my touch the line should not become smooth.line will be remain straight.

**i think i have to do something like**

```
  if (currentPoint.x > lastPoint.x){        
    currentPoint.y = lastPoint.y;
} 
else if (currentPoint.x < lastPoint.x) {
    currentPoint.x = lastPoint.x;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are moving subpixels you will get unwanted antialiasing. I suggest floor/ceil to a non float. This obviously gets more complicated when working with retina vs non retina.

Comment: actually i have to restrict touch, means if i get in vertical or horizontal touch i have to set points according to it.

Comment: i dont get answer by this answer , but it helps me to understood it in more detail.